# how do I debug a failed multi-stage Azure DevOps pipeline that fails to run a stage and produces no errors?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a multi-stage Azure DevOps YAML pipeline that had been running fine up until I included a block of parameters (in the part of YAML before the first stage).  Now, with these parameters, the Build stage continues to run. But the Release stage does nothing.  It doesn't produce an error, it just doesn't run.  I'm left with a message:

"Parent pipeline used these runtime parameters"

And then there is is a collapsible UI element you can expand to see the parameters, which isn't super helpful, given that I know what the parameters were.

The parameter block that is now making my multi-stage YAML pipeline fail without any helpful errors is this:

```js
  
parameters:
- name: configuration
  type: object
  default:
  - Texas
  - Arizona
```

Is it even possible to make a multi-stage YAML AzureDevOps pipeline that accepts parameters?  Or is that the limitation (seemingly undocumented) that I am running up against?

EDIT: Here's the whole YAML:

```html
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4
# Gus' first working multi-stage pipeline

trigger: none
 

pool:
  #windows-latest worked until Microsoft cnaged it to windows-2022 and i got
  #"The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 were not found."  error
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'  


  
parameters:
- name: configuration
  type: object
  default:
  - Texas
  - Arizona

variables:
  - name: solution
    value: '**/*.sln'
  - name: buildPlatform
    value: 'Any CPU'
  - name: buildConfiguration
    value: "Texas"


 
 

stages: 
- stage: build
  displayName: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build

  

    steps:
    - ${{ each configuration in parameters.configuration }}:
      - script: 'echo ${{ configuration }}'

 
 
  

      - checkout: self
  

      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script:  |
        
            cd $(build.sourcesdirectory)
 
 

      #without this first one, bad things happen!!
      - task: NuGetCommand@2
        inputs:
          command: 'restore'
          restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
          feedsToUse: 'config'
          nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'
          
      - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1


      - task: VSBuild@1
        inputs:
          solution: '$(solution)'
          msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
          platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
          configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

      - task: VSTest@2
        inputs:
          platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
          configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          ArtifactName: 'drop'
          publishLocation: 'Container'


- stage: Release
  displayName: Release
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  
  
  jobs:


      - deployment:
        displayName: Release
        environment: 
            name: QA
            resourceType: VirtualMachine
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:

              steps:
              #- script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber) with ${{ parameters.configuration }}
 
              - task: CopyFiles@2
                inputs:  
                  SourceFolder: '$(Agent.WorkFolder)\1\drop'
                  Contents: '**\*.zip'
                  OverWrite: true
                  TargetFolder: 'C:\QA\Web Sites\${buildConfiguration}'
```

Comment: can you share your whole yaml?

Comment: Ok, It's all there now.

Comment: So, parameters lists are finnicky, they give you the possibility to choose from a list at runtime (when you manually execute the pipeline) but they are not going to allow you to iterate it. 
Your best bet is to create a template and invoke it twice and pass a parameter into it with texas first and arizona after.
e.g. 

```- template: yourtemplate.yaml
   parameters: 
     configuration: Texas 
- template: yourtemplate.yaml
   parameters: 
     configuration: Arizona```
[templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Quick question for which I can find no answer:  can an Azure DevOps pipeline template be multi-stage?

Comment: well what you do is you create two stages and use the same template under multiple stages.
An example is this, i'm using one stage to build my app and two separate stages to deploy to two environments, but the templates i'm using in the deployment stages are the same, just different parameters.
Also you can always put conditions on tasks if needed, in that way if you want to selectively run a task you can just use the condition (true false for example) to run it